# Getting minute difference between 2 dates without 60 second calculation

Tags: swift, date

I want to get minute difference between 2 dates but unlike the other answers in stackoverflow, I don't want to calculate with seconds.

**What I mean is :**

(year-month-day hours-minutes-seconds)

- 2023-04-17 13:42:00
- 2023-04-17 13:43:00

between these 2 dates there is only 1 minutes difference.

- 2023-04-17 13:42:58
- 2023-04-17 13:43:00

**If I changed to first date's seconds to 58, I still want output as 1. Technically, difference is only 2 seconds but minute is different and difference is 1.**

You might think, take only the minute part from date and calculate but difference between these 2 dates might be much far, like months away so it would be hard to calculate like that or I could not find a way to do it.

Codes I have tried :

```
let diff = Int(end.timeIntervalSince1970 - start.timeIntervalSince1970)

let hours = diff / 3600
let minutes = (diff - hours * 3600) / 60
```

This one obviously calculate the minutes based on seconds so if seconds difference is less than 60 but still 2 dates are on different minutes, output is 0.

I also tried .dateComponents

```
let calendar = Calendar.current

let startDate = Date() // replace with your start date
let endDate = Date() // replace with your end date

let components = calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: startDate, to: endDate)

if let minutes = components.minute {
    print("Number of minutes between start and end dates: \(minutes)")
}
```

But also the same problem here.

Comment: Have you tried Calendar+ DateComponents?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292887-datecomponents You can define precisely which components you want to consider.

Comment: Can you provide any code which shows what you have tried?

Comment: What you want is the second difference + 30 secondes divided by 60 (number of seconds in I e minutes). Take the floor of this result or convert it to Int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that calculates the difference. It starts by using the same method you use but checks if the result in minutes is zero and of so uses a second function from `Calendar` to see if the dates are exactly the same or not and then equal comparing down to minutes, `isDate(:equalTo:toGranularity:)`

```
func minuteDifference(from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date) -> Int {
    let minutes = calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: startDate, to: endDate).minute!

    if minutes != 0 {
        return minutes
    } else {
        let factor = startDate <= endDate ? 1 : -1
        return calendar.isDate(startDate, equalTo: endDate, toGranularity: .minute) ? 0 : 1 * factor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the logic here is "take the largest unit of difference, and round it up to 1 of the next larger unit of difference".

The comments mention using `DateComponents`, which is definitely the correct starting point, but I don't see any built in way to do precisely this. E.g. if your set of components is `[.minute]` but doesn't include `.second`, you just lose the second granularity entirely. You won't see it rounded up to a 1 minute difference just because you didn't ask for the difference in seconds.

Here's how I would start:

```swift
import Foundation

extension Date {
    static private let allComponents: [Calendar.Component] = [.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
    static private let allComponentsSet = Set(allComponents)
    
    static func approximatedDifference(from start: Date, to end: Date) -> DateComponents {
        var differenceComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents(Self.allComponentsSet, from: start, to: end)
        
        // E.g. for `2023-04-17 13:42:58` and `2023-04-17 13:43:00`, this will be `.second`.
        let largestDifferingComponent = Self.allComponents.first(where: { differenceComponents.value(for: $0) != 0 })!
        
        // This is the next large component. E.g. if `largestDifferingComponent` is `.second`, then this will be `.minute`.
        let largerComponentIndex = Self.allComponents.index(allComponents.firstIndex(of: largestDifferingComponent)!, offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: 0)!
        let largerComponent = allComponents[largerComponentIndex]
        
        // Zero out the smaller differing component
        differenceComponents.setValue(0, for: largestDifferingComponent)
        // Increment the difference in the next larger component
        differenceComponents.setValue(differenceComponents.value(for: largerComponent)! + 1, for: largerComponent)
        
        return differenceComponents
    }
}

let start = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2023, month: 04, day: 17, hour: 13, minute: 42, second: 58).date!
let end = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2023, month: 04, day: 17, hour: 13, minute: 43, second: 00).date!
print(Date.approximatedDifference(from: start, to: end)) // 1 minute
```

It works correctly for your example, but you'll need to clean up some of those first unwraps (though some of them seem unfailable).

Answer (score -2):

first, you can split(if its a String), and convert to Minute unit:

> int minute = minute + hour * 60 + day * 1440 (you need handle leap year)

Simply sub result of 2 converted time

> int diffirence = minute2 - minute1